# In mysql, are stored procedures more efficient?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures

See this [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880/are-stored-procedures-more-efficient-in-general-than-inline-statements-on-moder). I am interested in the same question, but specifically for mysql.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do. Read this explanation [Mysql stored procedures - MySQL Stored Procedures Ain’t All That](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24744)