# In-Out Parameter for SqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following parameter for SqlCommand. How do I make it to both in and out the paramter value for the Stored Procedure.

```
 SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("aspInsertZipCode", mySqlConnection);
 mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRows", dataStringToProcess.ToString());
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var pInOut = mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRows", dataStringToProcess.ToString());
pInOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

And then to read the output value after you've executed the command:

```
// assumes that the parameter is a string and that it could possibly be null
string value = Convert.IsDBNull(pInOut.Value) ? null : (string)pInOut.Value;
```

Comment: public SqlParameter Add(string parameterName,SqlDbType sqlDbType,int size). Based on this, how should I define the size for size? In stored procedure, it is VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: @Lijo: I think that [the examples on MSDN use -1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx) for `VARCHAR(MAX)` etc. So it would be something like `var pInOut = mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRows", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1); pInOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput; pInOut.Value = dataStringToProcess.ToString();`

Answer (score 7):

`SqlParameter` has a `Direction` enumeration.  Set this value.

Then use the `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` that takes a `SqlParameter`.

Parameter direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx

You then pull the value out after having called `ExecuteNonQuery` (for example), by getting the `Value` from the parameter out of the command collection:

`myCommand.Parameters["@paramName"].Value`

Can't remember, but I think there is a string indexer on that.

**Alternatively, there is this one liner:**

`myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", value).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;`

Comment: Should I use  mySqlCommand.Parameters[0]? Any other way to define the direction while adding it to the parameter collection itself?

Comment: @Lijo I've added an example of a one-line command that you can use.  Also, Add is deprecated in favour of AddWithValue I believe.

Comment: [AddWithValueis often a bad idea to use](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)  and I really don't recommend it, especially if you are working with a `string`. `AddWithValue` will create a `nvarchar` parameter, if you are working with a direct query and you compare your `nvarchar` parameter to a `varchar` column it will cause the column to be cast from `varchar` to `nvarchar`, this will cause any indexes on that column not to function.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I suppose that stands to reason with Unicode being the standard in .NET. That said, there is always the option to fall back onto the other mechanism where you get to state the type. Also, if your stored procedure takes a `varchar` or other string-like non-`nvarchar` column, `AddWithValue` copes with that too. That's an interesting link you've provided, but I disagree with the blanket ban idea. Unit testing and database profiling should cover those issues.

Answer (score 3):

One of the attributes of a SQL Command Parameter is the Direction. You would want to use (going off of memory)

```
SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("aspInsertZipCode", mySqlConnection);
mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRows", dataStringToProcess.ToString());
mySqlCommand.Parameters("@DataRows").Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

Comment: Typo on last line. Parameters is not a method, it's a collection. Therefore that block should be...

`SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("aspInsertZipCode", mySqlConnection);
mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRows", dataStringToProcess.ToString());
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@DataRows"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlParameter DataRows = new SqlParameter("@DataRows", SqlDbType.Text) 
{ Value = dataStringToProcess.ToString(), Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput};
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(DataRows);
```