# Call stored procedure and return a message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure (declared parameters are missing but I don't have problems with that):

```sql
DECLARE @TotalRegistros AS INT = 0
DECLARE @ShowMsg AS NVARCHAR(50)    

SELECT @TotalRegistros = COUNT(*) 
FROM Tbl_Productos 
WHERE IdProducto = @Producto

IF @TotalRegistros < 3
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tbl_Productos (IdProducto, UnidadMedida, Precio, Activo) 
    VALUES (@Producto, @Medida, @Precio, @Activo)

    SET @ShowMsg = 'All fine!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @ShowMsg = 'Error, you already have 3 rows.!'
END

SELECT @ShowMsg
```

I execute this stored procedure with this C# code:

```cs
public string ExecuteSP(Producto prod)
{
    int res = 0;
    string resp = "";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPName", conn);

    try
    {
        Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", prod.Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medida", prod.Tipo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precio", prod.Precio);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activo", prod.Active);

        //CodeUpdated
        SqlParameter returnMessage = new SqlParameter("@ShowMsg", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        returnMessage.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(returnMessage);

        res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        resp = returnMessage.Value.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        Close();
    }

    return resp;
}
```

I know that I need to add something like `OutputParameter` and add the `@ShowMsg` but I don't know exactly how to do it! and the main problem is that I execute this code from a **WebMethod** with this code:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public string ExecuteC#Code(int id, string medida, string precio, string activo)
{
    string respuesta = "Error";

    try
    {
        Producto prod = new Producto(id, medida, precio, activo);
        //Code updated
        string resp = conn.ExecuteSP(prod);

        if (resp == "All fine!")
            respuesta = "Operacion realizada existosamente";
        else
            respuesta = "Already 3 rows with same Id..."
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        respuesta = "A ocurrido un error: " + ex.Message;
    }

    return respuesta;
}
```

Like I said, I have an idea of what I need to do to get the message after execute the stored procedure, but then I don't have any idea of how can I send that message to my web method. I know that I need to change the data type of my methods because I'll expect a `string` instead of an `int`.

Comment: You are selecting `@ShowMsg`, not returning it as a parameter. You therefore need `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: You need to define output parameters -- and since you didn't include you parameters that could be wrong too, but you should also stop using AddWithValue: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-Out Parameter for SqlCommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815781/in-out-parameter-for-sqlcommand)

Comment: You might only need out, but you should figure it out from there.

Comment: I updated my code, but now the problem is that I always get this message `Already 3 rows with same Id...` and when I display only `string resp = conn.ExecuteSP` I get 0.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a SQL Server scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserNameByID](@UserID int)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserName nvarchar(max);

    SET @UserName = (SELECT TOP (1) [Login] 
                     FROM [dbo].[Users] 
                     WHERE ID = @UserID)
    RETURN @UserName
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved! This is what I modified from my code:

Stored procedure:

```
Declare @ShowMsg as nvarchar(50) TO Declare @ShowMsg as int 

set @ShowMsg = a number (10, 20, whatever)
```

C# code:

```
public string ExecuteSP(Producto prod) TO public int ExecuteSP(Producto prod)

SqlParameter returnMessage = new SqlParameter("@ShowMsg", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

to

```
SqlParameter returnMessage = new SqlParameter("@ShowMsg", SqlDbType.Int);

resp = returnMessage.Value.ToString(); to Convert.ToInt32(resp = returnMessage.Value);
```

WebMethod:

```
string resp = conn.ExecuteSP(prod); TO int resp = conn.ExecuteSP(prod);
```

And finally

```
if (resp == "All fine!")
        respuesta = "Operacion realizada existosamente";
    else
        respuesta = "Already 3 rows with same Id..."
```

To

```
if (resp == 10)
    respuesta = "Operacion realizada existosamente";
else if (resp == 5)
    respuesta = "Already 3 rows with same Id...";
```

Comment: Could be because it's not a good way of doing, and future readers must be warned about it. If you have a text message from a stored procedure to display, you either return it in an output parameter or select in a resultset. You failed to explore either of the options and instead squeezed the text in an int.