# Are there significant performance benefits from changing involved queries to stored procedures?

Tags: hana

Obvious security benefits aside, are there significant performance boosts yielded from modifying involved queries to stored procedures in a SAP HANA database?

If so, are there metrics I can use to gauge perceived benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the other solution before reading this one.

Essentially, I ran some tests and swapped out my project's dynamic queries to stored procedures and saw massive performance bumps.

I was reading the [SAP HANA Best Practices](http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_sql_script_reference_en.pdf) reference and came across this passage under Performance:

> Executing dynamic SQL is slow because compile time checks and query
>   optimization must be done for every invocation of the procedure.
>   Another related problem is security because constructing SQL
>   statements without proper checks of the variables used may harm
>   security.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 onward, all SQL statements, irrespective of whether it’s a SQL coming from inline code or stored procedure or from anywhere else, they are compiled and cached. So, stored procedures **won't** give you performance boosts. They do give you better abstraction, security and ease of maintenance.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414272/Stored-Procedures-DO-NOT-increase-performance)**.

As for SAP HANA, I tried comparing it with Microsoft SQL Server(**[This](http://db-engines.com/en/system/Microsoft+SQL+Server%3BSAP+HANA)** article sheds some light on it.) and I cannot definitively say that it does compile and cache inline queries but it **most probably** should if you're using a recent version.

Comment: I just ran some tests myself - and I'm seeing performance boosts up to five times over with stored procedures. Do you know where I can go to gauge  which SAP HANA versions cache inline queries?

Comment: @Louis93, That's interesting, read [Matt's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880/are-stored-procedures-more-efficient-in-general-than-inline-statements-on-mode) answer on the same issue before you check for SAP HANA's query optimizations. Having said that, it very well might be that this **particular** DBMS isn't on par with the rest of the field but I **highly doubt it**. I'll try to find out more.