# How to increase the performance of procedure

Tags: sql-server

Is it right way to write all query i.e. insert, update and select into a single procedure ?

What will be effect in performance of procedure ?

Or we have to call different procedure for every query. if it's right then what about performance if we call again and again different procedures?.

Comment: Read about 'Transactions.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea to encapsulate everything in same procedure. You will probably loose execution plan that way, and that is what can render your stored procedure inefficient.

I you want the exec plan to be cached and reused as much as it can, write one CRUD statement per procedure.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907/which-is-better-ad-hoc-queries-or-stored-procedures)

Comment: which one is good in performance wise if i call one by one procedures or one procedure which include all query i.e. insert ,select..

Comment: As stated, performance will be beter if you encapsulate one statement per procedure, not all-in-one. If you really need all-in-oe, then write three ins/upd/del SPs and use them from another 'root' SP. But I can't figure why you would need that.