# ASP.Net C# - Passing a variable into MySQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, variables, parameters

So I want to create a line graph with data from a MySQL table and I've managed to draw one using the code below.

However, I want to pass a variable 'moduleID' to the MySQL query and I have done so, however, I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate way to do so.  Should I pass a parameter instead and if so, how do I do that?

```
protected void chart(int moduleID)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    string comm = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE module_id=" + moduleID.ToString();
    MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "time";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "%";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        Chart1.DataSource = ds;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "score";
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error. Unable to obtain data at the moment.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Concatenating strings to form a query is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameters like:

```
string comm = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE module_id=@module_id";
MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(comm,conn);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@module_id", module_id));
MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
```

You should also enclose your connection and command object with [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx). This will ensure proper disposal of resource.

Also an empty `catch` is very rarely useful. You should catch specific exception first and then the base exception `Exception` in an object. Use that object to log the exception information or show in your error message. This will provide you help in debugging your application.

Comment: As a side-note: You should have a stored procedure on the database that does the SQL command, as good practice.

Comment: @SamHood, having a proc for every SQL query is a matter of opinion. I personally prefer using an ORM and using procs where some complex process involving multiple queries is involved.

Comment: Of course! I just mentioned it as an aside, generally it's a good practice to get into if you're a beginner, just in case anyone's reading who goes off and implements all their SQL in the application code :)

Comment: @SamHood, you are right, also others might find this discussion useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907/which-is-better-ad-hoc-queries-or-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1):

#### Step1: Create stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectScore
(@moduleID NCHAR(50))AS
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE module_id=@moduleID
```

#### Step2: Call the stored Procedure from Code

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr )) {
conn.Open();

// 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("SelectScore", conn);

// 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@moduleID ", moduleID ));

// execute the command
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    // iterate through results, printing each to console
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        ..
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Creating a stored procedure for a single query could be an overkill.