# Use SQL to show parent record FALSE if any child values are Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a collection of parent items and each has an indeterminate set of child items.  Each child item as an attribute that is `X` or `NULL`.  (Apologies for the odd Boolean structure, but that's what I have to work with.)

```
Parent  Child  Attribute
------  -----  ---------
  A       1       X
  A       2       X
  A       3      NULL

  B       1       X
  B       2      NULL
  B       3      NULL

  C       1       X
  C       2       X

  D       1      NULL

  E       1      NULL
  E       2      NULL
```

I want to identify parent items as True or False based on the child items.  One `NULL` value will result in a False return for that parent item.  Here are the desired results:

```
  A       False
  B       False
  C       True
  D       False
  E       False
```

The ideal solution would even handle a parent that has **no** child records (result is False).

I can do this using temporary tables.  That solution is fairly long and I don't think presenting it would add any value to this post.

**How can I do this with an SQL query using no temporary tables?**

I would present "things I've tried" but I don't know enough how to even start.

Comment: What should happen if a parent has no children at all ?

Comment: As stated above, "result is False".

Comment: Ah yes. Then @GordonLinoff 's solution will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is equivalent to `nor`.  You just want to know if any values are `NULL` -- or equivalently if all values are `'X'`.  Use `case` and `aggregation`:

```
select parent,
       (case when count(*) = count(attribute) then 'true'
             else 'false'
        end)
from t
group by parent;
```

To handle a parent with no children requires a list of parents, separate from this list:

```
select p.parent,
       (case when count(*) = count(t.attribute) and count(t.parent) > 0 then 'true'
             else 'false'
        end)
from parents p left join
     t
     on p.parent = t.parent
group by p.parent;
```

As a reminder, `count(*)` counts the number of rows in the result set.  `COUNT()` with an expression (including a column) counts the number of non-NULL values.  When these are the same, there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: The OP wants also to handle the case with no children, so the 2nd solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via aggregates..,when no attributes,i have kept the column as blank..

In summary assign true or false to each row and get min value

```
create table #test
(
id int,
name char(2)
)

insert into #test

select 1,'x'
union all
select 1,null
union all
select 2,null
union all
select 3,''

with cte
as
(
select  id,b.*
from #test t1
cross apply
(
select case when name is null or name='' then 'False' Else 'True' end as 'chk' from #test t2 where t2.id=t1.id ) b
)
select id,min(chk)
from
cte group by id
```

You can remove even cross apply:

```
with cte
as
(
select  id,case when name is null or name='' then 'False' Else 'True' end as 'chk'
from #test t1
)
select id,min(chk)
from
cte group by id
```

**Output:**

```
1   False
2   False
3   False
```

Comment: This uses a temp table as part of a stored procedure or possibly a view.   As I said, I want to handle it in a query.

Comment: I didn't get the handle it in a query part.does this mean in a single select

Comment: It means using an ad-hoc query instead of a procedural approach.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22970/122139.   This doesn't mean using a single SELECT -- it's possibly to nest queries, or use UNION; these easily allow multiple SELECTS.  It *does* mean not using a temp table.

Comment: Correction -- every solution here uses an ad-hoc query, so that's not the issue.  I don't want any temporary tables -- that's the issue.  Sorry for the wrong concepts.